# How to parse XML structure with javascript JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

This is the XML File:

```
<Test>
    <Category>
        <SubCat>
            <Name>Name</Name>
            <Properties>
                <Key>Key</Key>
                <Value>Value</Value>
            </Properties>
        </SubCat>
        <SubCat>
            <Name>Name</Name>
            <SubCat>
                <Name>AnotherName</Name>
                <Properties>
                    <Key>Key</Key>
                    <Value>Value</Value>
                </Properties>
            </SubCat>
        </SubCat>
    </Category>
</Test>
```

I would like to get the Name. But only the Name of the first SubCat.
And the properties key value. The problem is the SubCat exist two times.

I tried this:

```
$(xml).find('SubCat').each(function() {
    var name = $(this).find("Name").text();
    alert(name);

}
```

but this show the name of the first and the second SubCat.

i search for something like this.

```
rootElement(Category).selectallchildren(SubCat).Name for the first SubCat Name
rootElement(Category).selectallchildren(SubCat).(SubCat).Name for the second SubCat Name
```

And same explicit select for the Key and values

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ - should contain your answer

Comment: $(xml).find('SubCat').first()

Comment: i tried this    `$(xml).find('Category').each(function() {
         
                  
         $(xml).find('SubCat:first').each(function() {
           
              var name = $(this).find("Name").text();
              alert(name);

          });});` but it show me only the name of the first subcat item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is to make use of jQuery's ability to evaluate CSS3 selectors.

`SubCat:nth-of-type(1)` selects every first occurrence of `SubCat` with arbitrary parent elements.

So this should work:

```
$(xml).find("SubCat:nth-of-type(1)").each(function(){
    var name = $(this).find("Name").text(),
        property = { };    //use an object to store the key value tuple
    property[$(this).find("Properties Key").text()] = $(this).find("Properties Value").text();

    console.log(name, property);
});

//Output:
//Name Object { Key="Value" }
//AnotherName Object { Key="Value"}
```

Hopefully that's what you want; when writing my first answer I obviously misinterpreted your question, sorry for the confusion...

Comment: this works. But it shows me only the first Element SubCat with the Name "Name" of the Category. But i need the second on too. I need all SubCat's and their Names, from Category. All nextchilds under Category.

Comment: Ok, now I'm really confused. ;) But it all depends on the CSS selector used in `.find()`. If you only want `SubCat` elements that are direct childs of `Category`, use the selector `Category > SubCat`. Note that you'll then have to use `.find("Name:first").text()` to get the name. If I'm still misinterpreting you, please tell me exaclty which output you want to have...